# Como iterar un bucle for para acceder al ultimo elemento de la lista

Tags: python, array, async-await, array-bidimensional, asyncio

Estoy tratando de meter en una lista 3 identificadores que necesito guardar para poder realizar una rapida busqueda a traves de alguno de los otros identificadores.

y lo que tengo son 2 métodos asíncronos, en uno de ellos hago un envío de un mensaje y recibo un identificador, que guardo junto al identificador del mensaje que me han enviado a mi.

Mas adelante, en otro método asíncrono recibo por otro lado un 3º identificador que quiero guardar en dicha lista.

El problema que me encuentro es que me pisa o guarda mal el 3º identificador.

El código seria el siguiente:

```
lista = []

async def my_event_handler(event):
    try:
        texto = await client.get_messages()
        original_msg_id = event.message.id
        if texto:
            texto = event.message.text.rstrip()
            s = await event.client.send_message(canal_prueba, texto)
            message_id.append([original_msg_id, s.id])
            # Esto devolveria un array similar a [[1,2][3,4],[],...]
                print(message_id)
                print(message_id[0])
                print(message_id[0][0])


async def my_event_handler2(event):
    try:
        texto = event.message.text.rstrip()
        ticket_id = texto.split(" ")
        # Accedemos a la ultima posición de la primera fila de la lista
        for i in range(len(message_id), -1):
            # Acedemos a la ultima posición para insertar el ultimo identificador. 
            for i in range(len(message_id[i]), 2):
                message_id[i].append(ticket_id[2])
                # aqui deberia salir una lista similar a: [[1,2,5][3,4,6],[]...]
                # siendo 5 el ide correspondiente al primer mensaje enviado.
```

Seria mejor realizarlo con bases de datos, o igual mejor numpy? Es que para algo tan sencillo, me parece un rollo tener que utilizar un conectar, ademas de que cuanto menos recursos mejor...

Muchas gracias anticipado por cualquier ayuda!

Comment: Si hablas de menos recursos, pues los ciclos consumen muchos más y la necesidad computación aumenta, por lo que mejor sería una BD , además por que recorrer el array si solo vas a insertar la última posición, un simple ```.append()``` sirve

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @christian efectivamente lo hice con un simple .append() añado los 3 ids a una nueva lista y hago un clear de la vieja, porque necesito acceder ala posicion 2 de cada columna por decirlo de alguna manera, para añadir el ultimo id

Comment: La edición que has hecho al final significa que la pregunta ha sido resuelta? En ese caso te sugiero que escribas la solución en una respuesta, en lugar de una edición de la pregunta. Si de paso explicas por qué esa solución funciona para que la respuesta sea de mayor utilidad a otros, mucho mejor. Si no te apetece redactar una respuesta porque consideras que tiene poca utilidad para los demás, entonces podrías simplemente borrar la pregunta para que no siga apareciendo "sin responder".

Comment: El código que has puesto para `my_event_handler2` es confuso. Los dos bucles anidados no deberían usar la misma variable `i` para evitar confusiones. Además, un `range(len(...), -1)` siempre será vacío, por lo que nunca debería entrar en el primer _bucle for_. ¿No te vale con un algo tan simple como  `message_id[-1].append(ticket_id[2])`?

Comment: @abulafia esperaba que me dieran alguna otra manera de poder ya que realmente el problema no lo solucione como tal, apañe planteando la lógica de otra manera y añadiendo las variables a otra lista.

Comment: Si @ChemaCortes en la respuesta que puse y como comentaba en el comentario anterior consegui realizarlo añadiendo todo a una nueva lista.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He conseguido resolver el problema que tenia

He conseguido realizar la función que quería de esta manera:

```
ticket_id = texto.split(" ")
message_id[0].insert(2, ticket_id[2])
lista2.append(message_id[0])
#print("Lista2: ", lista2,  "Lista 1: ", message_id)
message_id.clear()
```

De esta manera inserto los 3 identificadores que queria dentro de una nueva lista y limpio la antigua para no tener que utilizar un array 2D